# Change primary action according to user journey?

Tags: user-journey

The page is about pension plans. There are info pages, simulation pages (to see what happens when changing the pension plan) and a retirement planner.

There are different ways users use the page. About 70% use the info page and then want to see what pension plan options they have, the next step is to order a new plan (primary intention) or plan a retirement (secondary intention).

About 30% of the users start the journey via retirement planning. In this case, the primary intention is to see the impact in the retirement planning and the secondary intention is to order the plan change.

[image]

So the question is, what to do about those journeys which change the primary and secondary intention. I see two options:

1. The primary action is always «order plan option» and the secondary will always be «plan retirement». (disadvantage: this is only right for about 70 % of the users)
2. Change primary and secondary buttons according to journey (disadvantage: the buttons are not consistently at the same place on the screen)

Which of these 2 options would you recommend or do you have another thought about this.

Comment: Is "plan retirement" a sub-page or child page of the simulation page? If it is, would a Back button work instead of a primary button?

Answer (score 0):

I think the situation is not only about buttons and their position, but about a selection of plan types (similar to [pricing plans](https://www.niceverynice.com/components-categories/pricing)), consequently prioritizing one over another is conditioning the user's freedom to choose.

Hence, the plans are usually always at the same level, with a color difference, almost always with a label or explanatory text of the characteristics, and sometimes with a highlight on the recommended plan. Rate plans or prices are not just buttons, they require more information to facilitate the user's decision.

About the question: *–what to do about those journeys which change the primary and secondary intention–* my answer is to give as much information as possible, or a synopsis if it has been explained before, or the main features summary, and allow the user decides what to do. If there is a preferred plan, the `Recommended` label

[image]